# ¿Cómo puedo enviar varias imágenes mediante ajax?

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, laravel

Estoy tratando de enviar multiples archivos por ajax el problema es que al enviarlos debo enviar todos los que menciono por su id de lo contrario no actualiza

> Este es mi codigo HTML
>
> ```
> <html>
>  <head>
>  </head>
>  <body>                                                                            
>    <input type="file" name="id" id="id">
>    <input type="file" name="social" id="social">
> </body>
> </html>
> ```
>
> He tratado de esta manera pero debo actualizar ambos campos u
>   obligatoriamente debo actualizar el primer file para que reciba y
>   actualice el segundo
>
> ```js
> > 
> >         $('#save-form').click(function () {
> >                 $.easyAjax({
> >                     url: '{{route('admin.apply_job.update', [$userDetail->id])}}',
> >                     container: '#updatePretemporal',
> >                     type: "POST",
> >                     redirect: true,
> >                     file: (document.getElementById("id","social").files.length == 0) ? false
> > :true,
> >                     data: $('#updatePretemporal').serialize()
> >                 })
> >             });
> > 
> >
> ```
>
> He intentado de esta manera pero de igual manera debo de modificar
>   ambos para que el segundo file se edite
>
> ```js
> > 
> >      $('#save-form').click(function () {
> >                 $.easyAjax({
> >                     url: '{{route('admin.apply_job.update', [$userDetail->id])}}',
> >                     container: '#updatePretemporal',
> >                     type: "POST",
> >                     redirect: true,
> >                     file: (document.getElementById("id").files.length == 0) ? false :true,
> >                     file: (document.getElementById("social").files.length == 0) ? false :true,
> >                     data: $('#updatePretemporal').serialize()
> >                 })
> >             });
> > 
> >
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para mandar varios archivos con ajax, lo que tenés que hacer es mandar request multipart.

El ejemplo de abajo usa `jQuery.ajax`, no se si funciona igual con `easyajax`.

La forma mas simple es usar la [api de FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/FormData).

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("id", document.getElementById('id').files[0]);
formData.append("social", document.getElementById('social').files[0]);


$.ajax({
   url: '{{route('admin.apply_job.update', [$userDetail->id])}}',
   type: 'POST',
   data: formData,
   contentType: 'multipart/form-data',
   cache: false,
   processData: false,
   success: function (html) {
      ...
  }
});
```